# Getting the host URL + the destination URL when

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, url

I am using an Ajax POST call to get some data from a file located on an other server, but I am getting my host URL + the destination URL as URL for my AJAX URL!

- My host URL: 192.168.1.2
- My destination URL: 192.168.1.7/var/www/html/pfe/ajax.php

How could I get the destination URL only?

```
var url = "192.168.1.7/var/www/html/pfe/ajax.php";    
$("#c1.on").click(function () {
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { on : true, pin : 16 },
        success: function(data){
            $("#c1.on").addClass("hide");
            $("#c1.off").removeClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

The URL I get: 192.168.1.2/192.168.1.7/var/www/html/pfe/ajax.php

Comment: AJAX is not normally allowed across domains. If you use IP addresses, any different address is considered a different domain.

Comment: You also need to put `//` before the server name or address. Otherwise it's treated as part of the path, not the server.

Comment: thank you for your explanation

Comment: If you have access to both servers in question (which you probably do seeing as how you're working on localhost), then you can look further into the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This allows you to, on the *receiving/response* server, set up and control who (what server[s]) are allowed to send/receive external AJAX cross domain requests. It's a security feature which is *on* by default.

Comment: There's also the `crossDomain` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL syntax is incorrect. If a URL doesn't have `//` in it, it's treated as a filename on the same server as the current page. So it should be:

```
var url = "//192.168.1.7/var/www/html/pfe/ajax.php";
```

The `//` indicates that the next component is the name or address of the server.

Not that this still may not work because of the restriction against cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: is there any solution to use ajax call from a server to another ?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on SO about cross-domain ajax. Read a few.